# carriage return in python 3.4 does not move to the left

Tags: python-3.4, carriage-return

When I use a carriage return in idle nothing seems to happen.

```
>>>print('2\r3')
23
>>> carriage_return = "I will use a carriage\rreturn"
>>> print(carriage_return)
I will use a carriagereturn
```

if i run the same lines through the command line it works fine.

```
>>>print('2\r3')
3
```

Is this an idle bug (and if so is there a work around) or am i missing something simple? My os is windows 7.

Comment: Not an answer, but I found a related e-mail archive: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2006-February/045277.html. That said, using carriage return this way is very uncommon. The fact that it is part of Windows' standard representation of a newline and is an old Mac representation of a newline are probably toward the top of the reasons why it's uncommon. I certainly wouldn't expect it to be portable across systems. (Or even across displays, as you discovered. E.g., how does it work using PuTTY for SSH?) What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the link, that was the answer i was looking for. I'm not trying to accomplish anything in particular just working through the O'reilly series. I've found that if i move on without understanding something it bites me later.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you will have to do a "new line" `\n` before you do a "carriage return" `\r`

Example:

```
>>>car = "carriage\n\rreturn"
>>>print (car)
carriage
return
>>>
```

[EDIT based on comments]

if the goal is to print over the previous line, the following can be used on Microsoft Windows

```
import sys

def print_and_return(string):
    #adding '\b' which moves the carriage back one character
    #based on length of the string
    sys.stdout.write(string.ljust(len(string)*2,'\b'))
    sys.stdout.flush()

#this will print to stdout, and 'return' position to start
print_and_return("string1")

#normal print, but starting at the start of the previous print
print("string2")
```

This will produce

```
string2
```

And will have overwritten the original string, you can put a `time.sleep()` between the two statements if you like to witness it.

However this will print over the first line, on the original line, but it will not delete the previous printed string, so if the second string is shorter than the originally printed string, the end of the originally printed string remains on screen.

```
print_and_return("string1=long")
print("string2")
```

will produce

```
string2=long
```

You can always return the length of the previous string, then add spaces to the end of the second string, which will then overwrite the additional characters with spaces.

```
import sys

def print_and_return(string):
    sys.stdout.write(string.ljust(len(string)*2,"\b"))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return len(string)

l = print_and_return("string1=long")

#normal print, but starting at the start of the previous print
#adding spaces to ensure the length is the same as previous printed string
print("string2".ljust(l))
```

this will now produce:

```
string2
```

HTH.

Comment: The goal it to return back to the beginning of the *same* line and overwrite the existing characters. Your answer will not do so; it will put the content on a new line.

Comment: @jpmc26, I have edited my answer with code to overwrite